# Якорь на React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет,
Делаю свое первое приложение на React.js и побольшей части это просто компонентная верстка. Как к ней прикрутить якорь? В хедере простая навигация на ниже описанные компоненты. Ниже пример моего App компонента. Заранее всем спасибо за ответы!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Header from './Header';
import Presentation from './Presentation';
import Services from './Services';
import AboutUs from './AboutUs';
import Microblog from './Microblog';
import Footer from './Footer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Presentation />
                <Services />
                <AboutUs />
                <Microblog />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день,

Попробуй использовать в своем приложении react-scroll. 
Подробное описание и примеры использования пакета по ссылке ниже:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Comment: Спасибо за совет, уже пробовал и как то не получилось... (

Comment: Если у меня не получается использовать какую-то новую функцию, я просто смотрю на примеры с использованием этой функции. Попробуйте и вы! Найдите на github готовый проект, где используется react-scroll, и посмотрите как там все устроено!